# adding the frequency column in R without using dyplr

Tags: r, frequency, r-table

I have a "wide" dataset where for each observation I measure a value from a bunch of  categorical variables. It is presented just like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | f |
| a | z | f |
| b | y | g |
| b | y | g |
| a | y | g |
| b | y | f |

this means that V1 has two categories "a" and "b", V2 has two categories "z" and "y", and so on. But suppose that I have 30 variables (a quite bigger dataset).

I want to obtain a dataset in this form

| V1 | V2 | V3 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | f | 2 |
| b | y | g | 2 |
| a | y | g | 1 |
| b | y | f | 1 |

How can I get it in R? with smaller datasets I use `transform(table(data.frame(data)))` but it doesn't work with bigger datasets since it requires to build giant tables. Can somebody help please?

I would like to get a "general" code that does not depend on the variables name since I will be using it in a function. And moreover, since the datasets will be big I prefer to do it without the function table.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In base R, with `interaction`:

```r
as.data.frame(table(interaction(df, sep = "", drop = TRUE)))
```

Or, with `table`:

```r
subset(data.frame(table(df)), Freq > 0)

#  V1 V2 V3 Freq
#2  b  y  f    1
#3  a  z  f    2
#5  a  y  g    1
#6  b  y  g    2
```

---

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(V1, V2, V3, name = "Freq")

#  V1    V2    V3     Freq
#1 a     y     g         1
#2 a     z     f         2
#3 b     y     f         1
#4 b     y     g         2
```

Comment: I edited my question, please have look and see if you could help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I assume your dataset `dt` contains only categorical variables and `Freq` represents the number of observations for each unique combination of the categorical variables.

As you want codes "without using `dplyr`," here is an alternative using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, Freq:=.N, by=c(colnames(dt))]
```